# Redirect From Login Form To User Form using ajax and json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

There is a login form with a login button(not server control) on that. I want to login to user.aspx after the checkout with database. so I have created a page : getlogin.aspx which will be connect to database and check the username and password . I will call this form( I mean getlogin.aspx) by $.ajax like below:

```
 $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        var pass = $('#txtPassword').val();
        var user = $('#txtUsername').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'get/login.aspx',
            data: { un: user, pa: pass },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loader_login').addClass('loader_ajax');
            },
            success: function (jsonMsg) {
                var result = jsonMsg.loggedIn;
                if (result == "false") {
                    //show err dialog
                }
                else {
                    //redirect to user page with username as query string
                    window.open(location.host + "/" + "User.aspx?user=" + user);

                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#loader_login').removeClass('loader_ajax');
            }

        });

    });
```

so in the success function :

```
    success: function (jsonMsg) {
        var result = jsonMsg.loggedIn;
        if (result == "false") {
            //show err dialog
        }
        else {
            //redirect to user page with username as query string
            window.open(location.host + "/" + "User.aspx?user=" + user);

        }
```

Iam going to check result . every thing is going in right place but the window.open not working at all ! how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue with you code to open window because `location.host` will return for e.g. `www.stackoverflow.com` then your full url will be `www.stackoverflow.com/User.aspx?user=SomeUser` and this is a valid url

So I think you have a popup blocker that is blocking your new opened window because the below code works fine

```
//redirect to user page with username as query string
window.open(location.host + "/" + "User.aspx?user=" + user);
```

Comment: should i use preventDefault of something like that ?

Comment: @Parkhid yes you can, but don't you want a new Window to open

Comment: @Parkhid what is inside jsonMsg and jsonMsg.loggedIn

Comment: just loggedIn as flag (boolean). the else will executed.. I have test that with a simple alert, alert is working but Window.Open is never executed.... at all

Comment: @Parkhid alright looks like you are checking for string instead of bool on this line if (result == "false") please make it like this if (result == false)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14714/discussion-between-hatsoft-and-parkhid)

Comment: @Parkhid if you else block is correct then the statement for window.open should also works because it is correct